# Update progress bar after AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please help me to how to update progress bar after AJAX request? Here is what I done so far:

```
function test(){

   var queue  = ["a","b","c","d","e"];

 $( "#dialog" ).dialog("open");
 $( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ max: queue.length});

    var execute_queue = function(index)
    {    

        $.ajax( {    
            url: queue[index],
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(json){

              if (json['error']) {
                console.log(json['error']);
              }
              if (json.response) {
                console.log(json['response']);
                }

                index++;    // going to next queue entry

                // check if it exists
                if (queue[index] != undefined)
                {
                    execute_queue(index);
                }
            }

        }); // end of $.ajax( {...

    }; // end of execute_queue() {...

    var index = 0;

    execute_queue(index); // go!
}
```

First I set progress bar maximum length by counting queue array:

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ max: queue.length});
```

What's the next step? If I am not wrong the next step is go around the index++ command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong:

```
$( "#progressbar" ).progressbar({ value: index+1});
```

before index++ does the job.